# Jquery methods to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following some JQuery methods and want to convert them into pure JavaScript in order to improve the performance of the webpage.

```
$(function() {
    $('#resultDetails').on('click', '.toggle', function() {
        var findChildren = function(tr) {
            var depth = tr.data('depth');
            return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
            }));
        };
        var el = $(this);
        var tr = el.closest('tr');
        var children = findChildren(tr);
        var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
        subnodes.each(function() {
            var subnode = $(this);
            var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
            children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
        });
        if(tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        } else {
            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();
        }
        return children;
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').on('click', function() {
        $('#showContent').html($(this).find('.content').html());
    });
    $('table th').on('click', function() {
        $('#showContent').html($(this).find('.content').html());
    });
    $('#resultDetails tbody tr').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Demo can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/wYmwT/1/. If table contains more than 2000 rows, it takes large amount of time to load.

Any help ?

Comment: This is not a coding service. What have you tried yourself? where are you stuck? What is your **specific** problem?

Comment: Your problem not comes from jquery but comes from your table can get more than 2000 rows. Use some kind of pagination and then problem solved... And btw, you should think about delegating events instead of create a handler for each element.

Comment: -1 for unreadable code. I'm tried of unreadable code, here, and at work...

Comment: @Virus721 Fixed it for ya.

Comment: Much better isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is not coming from jquery and I advice you to not think for one second to re-write your code again in Javascript bc it will take you a long long time and also you will find in the end one code with thousand of line that your can't later update.My Solution is to re-think again how to reduce as much as you can yuour events on the Table.Like for example u can use toggleClass() in the place of removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse') etc etc

Comment: I agree, also the findChildren function looks like some broken variant  of $(tr).find('*'). Re-implementing jquery in itself is never going to be fast or readable.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will work on these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't going to see a huge difference converting this to pure javascript. I'm sure common JQuery functions like selectors etc are already well optimized. It's unlikely you will be able to re-write this better than they have given your apparent level of experience.

I would recommend using the time instead to look at an infinite grid or pagination solution so you are not dealing with as many DOM elements at once. Also don't make anonymous functions for the table click events as then it will be creating a new function for every element when they are all doing exactly the same thing. Instead do something like:

`var clickFunction = function(event){...};`

`$('table tr').on('click', clickFunction );`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. Now I will concentrate on Event Delegation.